# Ever Encouraging Conversion?

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism, noahidism

Are there any situations where it is halachickly advisable to encourage someone to convert rather than be Noahide?

Comment: Oh, I saw the _Noach_-related tag and the title and thought the question was about עֵבֶר.

Comment: I recall reading that the child of a Jewish father is not to be turned away. I will look for a source

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57339/what-is-the-definition-of-zera-yisrael-please-read-description?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi Anthony Manning in his source sheet](https://rabbimanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Conversion-Part-1-Hashkafic-Foundations.pdf) (page 5-7) explores this question by quoting various primary sources that it could be a mitzvah actually to **encourage anyone** to convert.

Rabbi Eliezer Melamed in his collection [Peninei Halacha about Conversion](https://ph.yhb.org.il/category/%D7%92%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8/%D7%96-%D7%92%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9D/#_te01ftn7_8) (in footnote 8) brings a long list of sources about authorities who believe that it is a mitzvah to encourage the conversion of a child of a non-Jewish mother and a **Jewish father** ("Zera Yisrael"):

> לדעת רבים, למרות שלהלכה ילדים של אב יהודי ואם נוכרייה נחשבים גויים
> (קידושין סח, א), כיוון שאביהם יהודי הם נחשבים 'זרע ישראל'. וכשם שמצווה
> להציל את היהודי מהתבוללות וטמיעה בגויים על ידי גיור בת זוגתו הנוכרית,
> כך יש להשתדל להציל את זרעו מטמיעה בגויים על ידי גיור ילדיו.
>
> According to many opinions, even though that practically a child from
> a non-Jewish mother and a Jewish father is not Jewish, but since the
> father is Jewish they are considered "the seed of Israel" (זרע ישראל).
> And just like it is a mitzvah to save a Jew from assimilation and
> absorption within the nations by means of a conversion of his
> non-Jewish spouse, so too it is important to attempt to save the
> offspring from being mixed in the nations by the conversion of the
> child.